# Best practice for structuring module exceptions in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, circular-dependency

Suppose I have a project with a folder structure like so.

```
/project
    __init__.py
    main.py
    /__helpers
        __init__.py
        helpers.py
        ...
```

The module `helpers.py` defines some exception and contains some method that raises that exception.

```
# /project/__helpers/helpers.py

class HelperException(Exception):
    pass

def some_function_that_raises():
    raise HelperException
```

On the other hand my `main.py` module defines its own exceptions and imports methods that may raise an exception from `helpers.py`.

```
# /projects/main.py

from project.__helpers.helpers import some_function_that_raises

class MainException(Exception):
    pass
```

Now, I do not want users to have to do `from project.__helpers.helpers import HelperException` if they want to catch that exception. It would make more sense to be able to import the exception from the public module that is raising it.

But I cannot just move `HelperException` to `main.py`, which would create a circular import.

What would be the best way to allow users to import all exceptions  from `main.py` while those being raised in `/__helpers`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.

The idea is to put all exceptions in one file, then import them all in `main.py`. To make it clean and explicit, we define the `__all__` attribute of the module.

Here is the new file structure

```
/project
    __init__.py
    main.py
    /__helpers
        __init__.py
        exceptions.py
        helpers.py
        ...
```

Here is the `exceptions.py` file.

```
# /project/__helpers/exceptions.py

class MainException(Exception):
    pass

# Note that this also allows us to inherit between exceptions
class HelperException(MainException):
    pass
```

Then, we can import exceptions from that file without circular dependency.

Finally, we define `__all__` in `main.py` to make it explicit that the exceptions are to be imported.

```
# /projects/main.py

from project.__helpers.helpers import some_function_that_raises
from project.__helpers.exceptions import MainException, HelperException

__all__ = ['MainException', 'HelperException', ...]
```

As a reminder, `__all__` defines what will be imported by the statement `from project import *`. So, this both extends the desired behavior to [import star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) and makes it explicit that we want the exceptions to be imported from that file.

Some IDEs will even recognize `'HelperException'` being in `__all__` as a reference to `HelperException` and will not indicate unused imports. This leads me to think that this is the correct approach.