# Python __init__: Cyclic imports (again...)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.6

I'd like to divide some abstract code from its implementation and link the actual implementation as import in `__init__.py`.

My `'model/__init__.py'` looks like this:

```py
from .estimator import AbstractEstimator
# link default estimator implementation
from impl.tf import TF_Estimator as Estimator
```

However, TF_Estimator is a sub-class of `'model.AbstractEstimator'`:

```py
from model import AbstractEstimator
class TF_Estimator(AbstractEstimator):
    ...
```

How can I resolve this cyclic dependency?
Is there some way to "ignore" the import of `'TF_Estimator'` in `'model/__init__.py'`?

My target would be that I can run `"from model import Estimator"` and get `"TF_Estimator"` back in the end.

Comment: I believe I asked myself a similar question a while ago. Mine was about exceptions, but the core problem was to structure a package to avoid cyclic import. Can that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104895/best-practice-for-structuring-module-exceptions-in-python3

Comment: `model.AbstractEstimator` is just another name for `.estimator.AbstractEstimator`. Why can't you use that instead? The `model` namespace should be considered the public interface; it doesn't necessarily have to be used by your implementation.

Comment: @chepner: OMG, i did not see that obvious solution... Thanks!

Comment: @Olivier: Thank you for your pointer. I'll keep that in mind as a more general solution.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was pretty simple, thanks to @chepner:
Simply use `from model.estimator import AbstractEstimator` in TF_Estimator; This skips loading `'model/__init__.py'`